Convergence of empirical CDF $F_n(t-) \to F(t-)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$
I am aware of course of the law of large numbers asserting the convergence of the sample mean to its population counterpart (in probability or even almost surely). In the case of the empirical CDF $F_n(t) = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n I(X_i \leq t)$ the law of large numbers gives $F_n(t) \to F(t)$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ where $F(t) = P(X \leq t)$.
What I am having trouble clinching is the statement $F_n(t-) \to F(t-)$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ where $F_n(t-) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} F_n(t-\epsilon)$ and likewise for $F(t-)$. Does this result also follow from the law of large numbers?

It follows from the Glivenko−Cantelli theorem:
$$|F_n(t-\varepsilon)-F(t-\varepsilon)|\le|F_n-F|\infty,$$
so $$|F_n(t-)-F(t-)|=\lim{\varepsilon\to0}|F_n(t-\varepsilon)-F(t-\varepsilon)|\le|F_n-F|\infty,$$
where $|F_n-F|\infty\to0$ (almost surely).

Please pay attention to  $ F_n(t-)=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}I(X_i<t) $.
